# Return to default value after field equals zero

Tags: mysql, sql

So I need help in trying to make a database field where it's default 7 and each day minuses 1 until its 0 then the day count starts again from 7. Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: I don't get it. Show us some codes or what have you tried? Are you really asking for the design or a trigger or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT 7 - ABS(0-DAYOFWEEK(NOW()))` will work.

Of course, since there are only 7 days in a week, this will go 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,7. If you want it 0 indexed, use `SELECT 6 - ABS(0-DAYOFWEEK(NOW()))` to get 6,5,4,3,2,1,0,6.

I've interpreted your question somewhat liberally, however. If you actually want to count *8* days (7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,7), you want `SELECT 8 - (TO_DAYS(NOW())%8)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought it would be something like this, only I didn't know exactly what the syntax would be like.